# Mudar imagem de acordo com data específica

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, tenho um site onde aparece tal imagem de acordo que muda horário. Só que preciso agora que esse modelo apresente tal imagem especificada em determinada data até tal data. Por ex.

No caso estou usando um script similar a esse:

````
<script>
function rodarImagens(){
    var now = new Date();
    var agora = now.getDay();
    var hora = now.getHours();
    var data = now.getDate();
    switch (agora){
        case 0: //domingo
        break
        case 1: //segunda
            if(data >= 07 && data < 08){ document.write('<img src="images/amapolacalcados.png">');}
            if(data >= 09 && data < 10){ document.write('<img src="images/amorimcontabil.png">');}
        break
        case 2: //terça
            if(hora >= 10 && hora < 12){ document.write('<img src="imagem_terca_10_12.jpg">');}
            if(hora >= 12 && hora < 15){ document.write('<img src="imagem_terca_12_15.jpg">');}
        break
        case 3: //quarta
        break
        case 4: //quinta
        break
        case 5: //sexta
        break
        case 6: //sábado
        break   
    }
}
</script>```

Como eu alteraria esse código para ele aparecer as imagens somente no mês e datas especificadas?
Por ex. Janeiro aparece imagem1.png do dia 01/01/2021 ao dia 10/01/2021 e assim subsequente.

Quem puder me ajudar ficarei grato.
````

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia caro, entendo que sua duvida é pontual então darei uma resposta mais objetiva, com algumas dicas.

// -> Duas barras significa um comentário no código javascript, vou utiliza-lo para explicar partes do código

```
<script>
//exemplo de comentário, por isso aparece cinza

function pegaImagemBaseadoNaDataAtual() {
    var now = new Date();
    var mes = now.getMonth(); // esse método pega o mês de 0 (janeiro) a 11 (dezembro)
    var hora = now.getHours(); // pega a hora de 0 a 23
    //var data = now.getDate(); no seu código de exemplo essa variável não é usada
    var agora = now.getDay(); // pega o dia da semana de 0 (domingo) a 6 (sábado)
    //agora vai vir a magia, talvez possa ser complexo mas sem dúvida funcional
    var imagensComMesEDiaSemana =

        {
            0: //diz respeito a janeiro
            {
                0: // diz respeito a domingo
                {
                    10: '<img src="images/amapolacalcados.png">', // 10 da manhã de todos os domingos de janeiro
                    11: '<img src="images/amapolacalcados.png">' // 11 da manhã de todos os domingos de janeiro
                },
                2: // diz respeito a terça
                {
                    22: '<img src="images/amapolacalcados.png">', // 22 da noite de todas as terças de janeiro
                    23: '<img src="images/amapolacalcados.png">' // 23 da noite de todas as terças de janeiro
                }
            },
            11: //diz respeito a dezembro
            {
                6: // diz respeito a sábado
                {
                    10: '<img src="images/amapolacalcados.png">', // 10 da manhã de todos os sábados de dezembro
                    11: '<img src="images/amapolacalcados.png">' // 11 da manhã de todos os sábados de dezembro
                },
                3: // diz respeito a quarta
                {
                    18: '<img src="images/amapolacalcados.png">', // 18 da noite de todas as quarta de dezembro
                    19: '<img src="images/amapolacalcados.png">' // 19 da noite de todas as quarta de dezembro
                }
            }
        };
    if (undefined == imagensComMesEDiaSemana[mes] 
|| undefined == imagensComMesEDiaSemana[mes][agora]
|| undefined == imagensComMesEDiaSemana[mes][agora][hora]) {
        return '<img src="images/amapolacalcados.png">'; // imagem padrão caso não tenha imagem definida na variável "imagensComMesEDiaSemana" para aquela mes/diasemana/hora
    }
    return imagensComMesEDiaSemana[mes][agora][hora]; //se encontrou imagem retorna ela
}
</script>
```

> Para funcionar no seu site isso deve estar no topo da pagina e não onde vai aparecer a imagem, onde quer que a imagem apareça basta:

```
<script>
document.write(pegaImagemBaseadoNaDataAtual())
</script>
```

> para acrescentar novas imagens para cada hora, mês e dia de semana é necessário conhecer essa simples escala de data, a reitero aqui:

```
var mes = now.getMonth(); // esse método pega o mês de 0 (janeiro) a 11 (dezembro)
var hora = now.getHours(); // pega a hora de 0 a 23
var agora = now.getDay(); // pega o dia da semana de 0 (domingo) a 6 (sábado)
```

Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição!

> Agora para ao invés de utilizar dias da semana e hora, considerar apenas o dia do mês

```
function pegaImagemBaseadoNaDataAtual() {
    var now = new Date();
    var mes = now.getMonth(); // esse método pega o mês de 0 (janeiro) a 11 (dezembro)
    var dia = now.getDate(); // pega o dia de hoje baseado na quantidades de dias que o mês possui

 var imagensComMesEDia =

        {
            0: //diz respeito a janeiro
            {
                1: // diz respeito ao dia 1 de janeiro
                '<img src="images/amapolacalcados.png">' //imagem de 1 de janeiro
                ,
                2: // diz respeito 2 de janeiro
                '<img src="images/amapolacalcados.png">' //imagem de 2 de janeiro
                
            },
            11: //diz respeito a dezembro
            {
                6: // diz respeito a 6 de dezembro
                '<img src="images/amapolacalcados.png">' //imagem de 6 de dezembro
                ,
                3: // diz respeito a 3 de dezembro
                '<img src="images/amapolacalcados.png">' //imagem de 3 de dezembro
                
            }
        };
        if (undefined == imagensComMesEDia[mes] 
|| undefined == imagensComMesEDia[mes][dia]) {
        return '<img src="images/amapolacalcados.png">'; // imagem padrão caso não tenha imagem definida na variável "imagensComMesEDia" para aquela mes/dia
    }
    return imagensComMesEDia[mes][dia]; //se encontrou imagem retorna ela
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Eduardo, tem me ajudado bastante.

Comment: Eduardo, desconsiderando, dias da semana e horário, caso eu quisesse, colocar por dias do mês, por exemplo. Igual no seu exemplo:

11: dezembro,
   do dia 1 ao dia 31 de cada mês, porém cada dia é uma imagem diferente entendeu?

Comment: Ok, vou editar a resposta para se adequar ao caso do dia do mês

Comment: Certinho, fico aguardando irmão. Obrigado!

Comment: Prontinho, @realrcorrea

Comment: Eduardo, desculpe sem chato, mas ao carregar todo código no meu script, não retornou nada, (as imagens) defini como dezembro (0) e a data de hoje (11). Você testou esse código e deu certo pra você?

Comment: Opa amigão sem problemas. sobre sua dúvida: na verdade o 0 diz respeito a janeiro, então nesse exemplo seria (11)dezembro e (11) dia do mes